# SQL Server, remove all users' access right to a table object

Tags: sql-server-2008, security

As a clean up job, I am trying to remove all users' (including non public users) access right to a single table object (apart from superusers) and will subsequently grant new access rights. Is there a simple way to remove access rights to a table without using a cursor with system tables?

Comment: are you wanting to revoke a single users rights to all tables or all users rights to a single table?

Comment: use the normal revoke command with the public option   this revokes access to the table for all public users.

Comment: @Brian Not all users are in the public role. Sorry will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work below:

```
declare 
    @user_name sysname,
    @deny_cmd nvarchar(500)

declare UserCursor cursor for
select name
from sys.database_principals
where type in ('U', 'S')
and name not in ('dbo', 'information_schema', 'sys')

open UserCursor

fetch next from UserCursor
into @user_name

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @deny_cmd = 
        'deny select, insert, update, delete on object::UberSecureTable
        to ' + @user_name

    exec (@deny_cmd)

    fetch next from UserCursor
    into @user_name
end

close UserCursor
deallocate UserCursor
```

Let me know if that does what you're looking for.  Change **UberSecureTable** to your actual table name.

Comment: Thanks @Shark. This works and does the job, but I was looking to see if there's an admin command that can avoid using cursor. As an analogy, one can delete rows, but there's also the truncate command. I still up vote your answer though.